# R package lattice won't plot if run using source()

Tags: r, graphics, plot, lattice

I started using the `lattice` graphic package but I stumbled into a problem. I hope somebody can help me out.
I want to plot a histogram using the corresponding function.

Here is the file `foo.r`:

```
library("lattice")

data <- data.frame(c(1:2),c(2:3))
colnames(data) <- c("RT", "Type")

pdf("/tmp/baz.pdf")
histogram( ~ RT | factor(Type), data = data)
dev.off()
```

When I run this code using `R --vanilla < foo.r` it works all fine.

However, if I use a second file `bar.r` with

```
source("bar")
```

and run `R --vanilla < bar.r` the code produces an erroneous pdf file.
Now I found out that `source("bar", echo=TRUE)` solves the problem. What is going on here? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I'm using R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08) with lattice_0.19-30

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is in the [FAQ for R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f) -- you need `print()` around the lattice function you call:

> 7.22 Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?
>
> The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the
>   graph. Lattice functions such as xyplot() create a graph object, but
>   do not display it (the same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis
>   graphics in S-Plus). The print() method for the graph object produces
>   the actual display. When you use these functions interactively at the
>   command line, the result is automatically printed, but in source() or
>   inside your own functions you will need an explicit print() statement.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! It took me a lot to time to find out what the actual problem was. Thanks a lot!

This works:
`... print(histogram( ~ RT | factor(Type), data = data)) ...`

Comment: Should this be applicable to the `plot()` function from the `graphics` package? I'm seeing similar behavior, but this doesn't seem to fix it..

Comment: Ahh. `plot` works *without* the print statement, but you need to use dev.new() or similar before plotting.

Comment: I added an example for this case here http://stackoverflow.com/a/44098042/54964 because I think the answer is stub.

Answer (score 2):

Example of the case

1. `visualise.r`

   - calls `plot2this.r`

     - calls `ggplot2` and returns `p` object

Here the fix in the function `plot2this.r` from `return(p)` to `return(print(p))`.

Initial `plot2this.r`

```
p <- ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill=variable)) 
return(p)
```

Fix

```
p <- ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill=variable)) 
return(print(p))
```

Output now: expected output with the wanted plot.

Comment: Great work specifying the code for outputting a `ggplot`. Thanks! +1.