# ggmap doesn't show maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have the following code:

```
library(ggmap) 
ggmap(get_map(location=c(lon = 5.218922, lat = 52.342366), zoom =14))
```

Which by my account should work fine, but I only get a standard ggplot2 image (grey background, etc), with the correct axis, but without the map shown:
[image]

When I look in my working directory I do find a file called "ggmapTemp" which has the correct map in it. But the map is not shown by ggplot2.

I work with RStudio and have limited rights on my work pc. Could this be the reason that the map is not shown correctly? My version of RStudio is 0.96.316 and R is R-2.15.1.

```
> sessionInfo()
 R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
 Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
 [5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] ggmap_2.1     ggplot2_0.9.1

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       grid_2.15.1       
 [5] labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-18        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3       
 [9] plyr_1.7.1         png_0.1-4          proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5
 [13] reshape2_1.2.1     RgoogleMaps_1.2.0  rjson_0.2.9        scales_0.2.1      
 [17] stringr_0.6        tools_2.15.1
```

**Update:**
My sessionInfo() after answer 1:

```
sessionInfo()

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] mapproj_1.1-8.3 maps_2.2-6      ggmap_2.1       ggplot2_0.9.1  

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1    dichromat_1.2-4     digest_0.5.2        grid_2.15.1        
 [5] labeling_0.1        MASS_7.3-20         memoise_0.1         munsell_0.3        
 [9] plyr_1.7.1          png_0.1-4           proto_0.3-9.2       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 
 [13] reshape2_1.2.1      RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.2 rjson_0.2.9         scales_0.2.1       
 [17] stringr_0.6.1       tools_2.15.1
```

As requested:

```
capabilities()
jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets   libxml     fifo 
TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE 
cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you add the versions of R and ggmap you are using to your question.

Comment: That code works for me on the R console and RStudio. I get a map of somewhere in Holland just east of Amsterdam.

Comment: The location of the map is correct. My version of RStudio is 0.96.316 and R is R-2.15.1.

Comment: I don't see `mapproj` there, but I needed it to be able to get the plot.

Comment: Can you run the capabilities() function and paste in the output. I reckon you've not got PNG support...

Comment: Compiling R without png, tiff, and cairo in my capabilities() I still get the image - but that might be a Linux feature using the Xlib system.

Comment: @Timror I have this error as well. I also assumed that it was because I have limited rights on my work PC as it works for me too outside of the Terminal Server I use at work.

Comment: Does anybody have a solution to the problem? I running into a similar problem and would like to see this question resolved. The following code produces a blank plot on one machine, but works on the other: `require(ggmap); qmap("baylor university", zoom = 14, source = "osm")`.

Comment: I also looking forward to yet another solution. Maybe that's something with graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error but it is solved now that I upgraded to the latest version of ggmap (V2.3)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, updating to latest (2.7) didn't help -- nor did installing from the Github.

Answer (score 7):

On my machine, the list of attached packages is:

```
other attached packages:
[1] mapproj_1.1-8.3 maps_2.2-6      ggmap_2.1       ggplot2_0.9.1
```

This means you probably need `mapproj` as well as `maps` to run your code, since these are suggested packages from `ggplot` to enable correct map projections.

Try:

```
install.packages(c("mapproj", "maps"))
```

then rerun your code.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised the OP doesn't get an error without `mapproj` installed. I didn't have it installed and it mentioned that `mapproj` was required to do this, but it worked fine after installing it (hence my comment).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not solve my problem. I still get the same result after installing both packages. I have updated all my other packages as well.

Comment: I have the same problem, when I use the option filename for get_map and go to the directory the file is saved the map image is there - it just does not plot when I use ggplot(map). I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Reinstalling ggmap fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the solution was in graphics itself. Something has changed my color depth to 16-bit, so changing to 32-bit resolved problem.

Answer (score -2):

So if you are a RStudio user like myself, you have to remember that code in a .R acts slightly differently than running code from the R command line.  The code below, taken from [Max Marchi's R blog](http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=534), works perfectly if executed from the command line.

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
map <- get_map(location = 'England', zoom = 7)
ggmap(map)
```

However, take the same code above and place it within a .R in RStudio, and the result will be a blank window where a map was expected to appear.  To fix this problem, place `ggmap(map)` inside of `print()` like the code below.

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
map <- get_map(location = 'England', zoom = 7)
print(ggmap(map))
```

The code above should produce a map of England in the plotting window.  At least it does for me.

My explanation for this may be incorrect so don't hold me to it.  Since RStudio runs on top of R, you need to explicitly tell RStudio that certain commands are line commands and need treated like such.  By placing the line command inside of `print()`, RStudio knows to execute that command within R's command line.

I welcome comments and a better explanation of what is going on.

Comment: This isn't the issue the user is having. You need to call `print` when running code that calls trellis/lattice/ggplot code from source, see: Calling `print` isn't an RStudio related issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783120/r-package-lattice-wont-plot-if-run-using-source . When you don't call `print`, nothing displays at all. In this case, the user is getting an empty ggplot window.

Comment: not a RStudio issue, and not related to the question