# rRharts shows in Rstudio and browser but not R viewer

Tags: r, rcharts, graphing

Morning Community,

I wanted to ask a quick question regarding `rCharts` graph outputs compared to native R.

Question 1: Why are graphs from `rCharts` displayed in my browser rather than the viewer in R?

Question 2: How can I force (or choose to use) the graphing function in native R instead?

See these two screen shots:

[image]

Code for native R:

```
# Simple Scatterplot
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example", 
    xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)
```

Code for rChart:

```
library(rCharts)

myData

plot<-Highcharts$new()
plot$chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line",height=NULL)
plot$xAxis(categories=myData$Subject.ID, tickmarkPlacement= 'on', lineWidth=1)
plot$yAxis(gridLineInterpolation= 'circle', lineWidth=1, min=NULL,max=NULL,endOnTick=T,tickInterval=10)
plot$series(data = myData[,"A"],name = "A", pointPlacement="on")
plot
```

rChart Data used

```
   Subject.ID  A  B  C
1           1 65 29 60
2           2 87 67 59
3           3 98 54 24
4           4 67 44 23
5           5 54 50  4
6           6 83 60 54
7           7 82 55 27
8           8 80 48 32
9           9 88 56 44
10         10 68 68 56
11         11 90 76 69
12         12 41 47 45
13         13 NA 82 NA
14         14 NA 55 NA
```

Ps: As an aside, I understand that I am graphing two different functions, a scatterplot vs radar plot. My goal is to understand whether or not native R can display (or perhaps another word) the graph output from rCharts - Even if I lose interactivity.

Comment: I wanted to add that the viewer works in R Studio. As-in, it does not open a browser to view it. [Link](https://imgur.com/lNNvbwx)

Comment: The whole point of rCharts (at least as I understood it) was to avoid using the interactive plotting devices and rather to "publish" graphics on a web-capable device that supported interaction via a server. The existing mechanisms depended on Rscript which was more limited and not designed to use an HTML/XML client.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding of your reply was that rChart was designed with with user interactivity through the web while Rscript (The native R viewer) was not. With this said, would I be able to take a 'snapshot' of the rChart output and display that in the native R viewer? Based on what you have said, this would be a R function(command?) that will take HTML script, generate it, and display the 'image' (or perhaps another word) within the R viewer.

Comment: @bondeddust I don't know if I am allowed to ask a question in two parts, but the question I have today is similiar to the question posed here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783120/r-package-lattice-wont-plot-if-run-using-source/6783165#6783165) and answered by 7.22 of the R FAQ [Link](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html). Plotting a rChart `highchart` when sourced. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704713/r-command-grammar-or-perhaps-another-word) would be the deleted question that housed my previous question.

Comment: The Rscript program is _not_ the typical viewer. It is a program that is designed to run pre-canned programs on an as-needed or as a time-scheduled process. I was trying to contrast this with another server-type functionality.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you for always providing a quality response bondeddust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached out to the developer for rCharts and he has replied back to me:

"The native viewer that comes with the R GUI is NOT capable of displaying html. So, the only way to view html output like what rCharts generates is to use the browser. The RStudio viewer on the other hand is capable of displaying html and so rCharts takes advantage of that."