# Saving plots to working directory - plots are blank?

Tags: r, plot, cairo

I want to automatically write the output of my plots to my working directory. Also, I have structured my script in a way so some computation steps and plots are dependent on a preceding variable. Like this, some computation steps are skipped in case they are not necessary anymore or I am computing a different scenario.

I am facing the following problem: the plot is correctly saved to the working directory if I call the function simply without the `if` condition. However, once I call the function within the `if` condition, only a **blank plot** is written to the working directory.

The following reproducible example demonstrates the issue (please replace the path of the working directory):

```
##Set WD (!! replace with own path)

setwd("C:/Users/deca/Desktop")

##Initiate packages

install.packages("effects")
install.packages("Cairo")

require(effects)
require(Cairo)

##Initiate data set and condition

varL <- rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 10)
varP <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
entry <- as.factor(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

dat <- data.frame(varL, varP, entry)

condition <- "YES"

##Define regression

hx1 <- glm(entry ~ varL*varP, data = dat, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

##Plot within R graphic device - works perfectly fine

plot(effect("varL:varP", hx1))

##Save plot to WD without if condition - works fine

Cairo(file=as.character("plot1"), 
      type = "png",
      units = "px", 
      width = 715, 
      height = 489, 
      pointsize = 12, 
      dpi="auto")
plot(effect("varL:varP", hx1))
dev.off()

##Save plot to WD with if condition - This is very the problem surfaces

if(condition == "YES") {

    Cairo(file=as.character("plot2"), 
        type = "png",
        units = "px", 
        width = 715, 
        height = 489, 
        pointsize = 12, 
        dpi="auto")
  plot(effect("varL:varP", hx1))
  dev.off()

}
```

Where is this problem coming from? How can I solve it within `Cairo`? How can I save plots to the `WD` so it works, potentially using a different solution other than `Cairo`?

Comment: I think this is one of these `print(plot(effect(..` questions.

Comment: maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783120/r-package-lattice-wont-plot-if-run-using-source

Comment: @user20650 I now put the `plot` command into `print()`. That works, thanks and sorry for asking this maybe otherwise obvious question, but I did not come across the question you linked during my search...

Comment: no need for apologies.. it seems the plot effect function is based on `lattice`, which is based on `grid` - these need to be printed (as do `ggplot`s) . Im going to close this as a duplicate, so others are directed to the answer at the link above.